# How to mount local disk on Ubuntu

Tags: mount

i am using ubuntu on my server and only access i have is via SSH.

I need to add new disk to it but i am not able to do it how ever i try. I hope for your help:

Output for : `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/xvdb: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
22 heads, 22 sectors/track, 216647 cylinders, total 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf9f9aaff

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvdb1            2048   104857599    52427776   83  Linux

Disk /dev/xvda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bbcb7

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1            2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/xvda2          501758    16775167     8136705    5  Extended
/dev/xvda5          501760    16775167     8136704   8e  Linux LVM

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/xvdd'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/xvdd: 711 MB, 711983104 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 86 cylinders, total 1390592 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x42671707

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvdd1   *           0     1390591      695296    0  Empty
/dev/xvdd2           86300       90651        2176   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/xvdd1'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/xvdd1: 711 MB, 711983104 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 86 cylinders, total 1390592 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x42671707

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvdd1p1   *           0     1390591      695296    0  Empty
/dev/xvdd1p2           86300       90651        2176   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

Disk /dev/mapper/TEST--AudaHistory--vg-root: 6148 MB, 6148849664 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 747 cylinders, total 12009472 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/TEST--AudaHistory--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/TEST--AudaHistory--vg-swap_1: 2143 MB, 2143289344 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 260 cylinders, total 4186112 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/TEST--AudaHistory--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

So as you can see there i have a disk xvdb with 53 GB but if i write :
`df -h` I can't see him there:

```
Filesystem                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/TEST--AudaHistory--vg-root  5.6G  5.0G  274M  95% /
udev                                    972M  4.0K  972M   1% /dev
tmpfs                                   399M  204K  399M   1% /run
none                                    5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                    997M     0  997M   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvda1                              236M   32M  192M  14% /boot
```

I try things like mount -l /dev/xvdb1  /var/www but always nothing happen and i get just response with help or i get response to write filesystem if i use ext4 or ntfs i just get auto respnse with help

Can somebody help me with that?
p.s. I see everywhere ppl forget to make dir with that name, i have dir /var/www for sure so problem is somewhere else:(

Comment: Have you tried mount /dev/xvdb1 /var/www without any options? also make sure you are root and the permissions for the mountpoint allow you to mount a drive there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not doing this from the root user (which I presume you aren't), you need to use sudo.

It should be as simple as `sudo mount /dev/xvdb1 /var/www`

Comment: Hey @Tobias, yea looks you are right. I forgot to use sudo. 
Anyway right now i am getting error: 
`mount: block device /dev/xvdb1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: you must specify the filesystem typ`

Comment: Try 
`sudo mount -t ext4 -o rw /dev/xvdb1 /var/www` this specifies the filesystem type (which shouldn't be necessary) and adds the read/write option.

Comment: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: Could try to leave out the '-o rw' part `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdb1 /var/www` . Does a `sudo fsck /dev/xvdb1` do anything?

Comment: `sudo fsck /dev/xvdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/xvdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>`

Comment: I'd say the filesystem is corrupt, if you didn't have any important data, I'd just reformat the drive and mount it with the command in my answer.

Comment: Tobias is there a chance you can tell me that as well? After that i will not disturb you

Comment: Follow http://superuser.com/questions/643765/creating-ext4-partition-from-console to create the partition, then follow my answer again. I'm afraid I can't help anymore than this.

Comment: I marked your answer as right, it helped me a lot to find out where  is a problem :)